# Chat star superposition desynchronisation

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

I was trying to star two messages in a chat room ([this one](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta), if it's important) and by chance did it too quickly, leading to chat rate-limiting me from actually starring the second one.

## Problem 2

> [image]
>   <sub>Use the giant S. I dare you.</sub>

## Problem 1

What's more interesting than the interesting pluralisation is that while the starring obviously didn't "take" server-side (due to rate-limiting), the client indicated (apart from that rate-limit message) that the star had "taken" just fine. This was confusing (I don't generally like things that indicate they're in states they aren't in), and it took a bit of clicking to get the chat window out of said superposition.

**tl;dr** Please do not allow the client to say you starred something when the starring failed.

Comment: "Use the giant S. I dare you."  Okay mister, now it's personal.